# Question about the Java objects' equals() method

Tags: java

I have a question about the object `X.equals(Y)`.

I use Sonar and it says that I have to move the `""` string literal on the left side of this string comparison:  `!date.equals("")`.

So I did that: `!("").equals(date)` but I don't really know if it is right or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "use "abc".equals(myString) instead of myString.equals("abc") to avoid null pointer exception" already problematic in terms of business logic?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/313673/is-use-abc-equalsmystring-instead-of-mystring-equalsabc-to-avoid-null-p)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When comparing a string variable to a string literal with .equals(), is there a standard practice for the order of items?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147650/when-comparing-a-string-variable-to-a-string-literal-with-equals-is-there-a)

Answer (score 1):

`!"".equals(date)` and `!("").equals(date)` and `!(("")).equals(date)` and `!(((""))).equals(date)` and `!("".equals(date))` all return the same thing.

So you correctly switched the string literal with the variable, you just added some not needed parentheses.